# c++: Timetable program

Tags: c++, timetable

I have to generate a timetable for 6 classes in a university. The following are the classes i have come up with.

```
class ClassRoom  
{  
    private:  
    char id[5];
    char type;
    int cap;
public:
    void setRoom();
    void disp();
}c[15];
class StudentGroup
{
    int sem;
    char group[3];
    int strength;
  public:
    void setGroup();
}stud[8];
class Course
{
    char courseID[7];
    int semNo;
    char courseCode[5];
    char courseName[50];
    char type;
    int lec;
    int tut;
    int prac;
public:
    void setCourse();
}cour[75];
class CourseDetails
{
    public:
  char courseID[7];
  char preference[3];
  char resourceType;
  char classPref[3];
};
class Faculty
{
  char facID[6];
  char name[50];
  int noCourses;
  public:

  CourseDetails cD[6];
      void setFaculty();
      void disp();
}fac[50];
class ElecPair
{
    int noPaired;
    char courseId[10][7];
public:
    void setElecPair();
}ePair[10];
class Period
{
    int semNo;
    char className[3];
    char courseID;
    char facID;
    bool availability;
};
class TimeTable
{
    Period prd[5][7];
}tt[6];
```

I have to create the timetable with the usual constraints:
No teacher can be in 2 classes at the same time.
No student can have 2 classes at the same time and so on.
I don't want the code but i would like to get suggestions on  the best possible way I can generate this timetable without using Genetic Algorithm.
PS:Is there a way i can use stack or recursion to generate this timetable?

Comment: Please clarify "best possible way":  shortest code?  Fastest algorithm?  Easiest to reuse?  Data Oriented?  Best for data cache?

Comment: yes you can do this wthout using generic algorithm........

Comment: Scheduling is np-hard. A GA is probably a decent method to use. Otherwise, brute force backtracking will work. Try each possible placement of student/teacher etc until you can't place someone, or until you reach a solution.

Comment: I was referring to Easiest to reuse @ThomasMatthews my professor wants it to be as generic as possible. Also I am pretty much a beginner with c++ so yes, i would definitely prefer the simplest method too..

Comment: Also could you be more specific as to what sort of code i could come up with @CodeProcessor

Comment: first of all make every member in the classes public because we can directly manipulate them from other functions which makes our code simpler.

Comment: What is each class used for?  For example what is ElecPair used for and when is it used?

Comment: ElecPair is a class containing the subject IDs for electives for the same class which take place at the same time @Jerry Jeremiah

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple algorithm in c# that can solve the timetable problem with 0 conflicts between teachers, rooms, and lectures in the same given time. 
Its idea is quite simple :
1- Generate the possible lectures for each teacher (teacher + period of time).
2 - generate the possible lectures for each room (room + period of time).
3- take a random period from a given teacher_periods  List and check two things.
 a - is this random period exists in room-periods ??
 b - is this random period not taken by the same class of students ??
if these two conditions are true then u have to do 3 things:
1- select a room with the same period and add it to a solution (in a solution list ).
2- remove this period of time from both teacher-periods and room-periods lists.
 otherwise, repeat the process.
 public class Program
    {

```
  static List<Room> rooms ;

    private static List<Room> GetListeOfRoomsFomSource()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static  void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listTeachers = GetListeOfTeachersFomSource();
        rooms= GetListeOfRoomsFomSource();
        foreach (var techer in listTeachers)
        {

            var temp = techer.periods.ToList();
            var rnd = new Random();
            var rnd2 = new Random();
            var period = 0;

            var exist = false;
            do
            {
                if (temp.Count == 0) break;
                int index = rnd.Next(0, temp.Count - 1);
                period = temp[index];
                exist = CheckIfLectureExist(period, section,techer);
                temp.Remove(temp[index]);

            } while (!exist);
            if (exist)
            {
                AddSolution( techer,period);
            }
            else
            {
                AddNoSolution();
                // list.Remove(tc1);
            }

        }




    }

    private static void AddSolution( Teacher item, int period)
    {
        // get a random room with the this given period;

        var lisOfrooms = new List<Room>();
        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            if (room.periods.Any(x=>x.Equals(period))) lisOfrooms.Add(room);
        }
        var rnd2 =  new Random();
        var r2 = rnd2.Next(0, lisOfrooms.Count());
        var availableRoom = lisOfrooms[r2];
        // create solution which is a combination of the techer + availableRoom + period  + class.
        //remove the period from the periods of the given techer;

        //remove the period from the periods of the given room;
        //r;
    }

    private static void AddNoSolution()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

   private static bool CheckIfLectureExist(int period, object classRoom ,Teacher teacher)
    {
       // chech if this period has an available (free) room in the list of rooms.
       // chech if this period + classroom + techer does not exist in the solutions to avoid the conflict between classes.
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static  List<Teacher> GetListeOfTeachersFomSource()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Teacher{
    public Teacher (int periodsWeek)
    {
      _periodWeek = periodsWeek;
      GeneratePerids();
    }
    int _periodWeek;
    public int[] periods {get;set;}
    public void GeneratePerids(){
        for (int i = 0; i < _periodWeek; i++)
        {
            //populate periods;
        }
    }

}
 public class Room
 {
    public Room (int periodsWeek)
    {
      _periodWeek = periodsWeek;
      GeneratePerids();
    }
    int _periodWeek;
      public int[] periods {get;set;}

      public void GeneratePerids(){
        for (int i = 0; i < _periodWeek; i++)
        {
            //populate periods;
        }
      }

 }
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: the implementation is too big . but i can add a pseudo code in order to explain it.